# SQL - Counting one attribute, grouping by another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `staff`

```
staff
pt | ward
P  | 1
P  | 1
T  | 1
P  | 2
T  | 2
```

I want to produce a table that counts how many P's and T's there is for each ward like this:

```
staff
ward | P | T
1    | 2 | 1
2    | 1 | 1
```

I have tried this

```
WITH cte(ward, P, T) AS(
SELECT ward,
(SELECT COUNT(PT) FROM staff WHERE PT = 'P' ),
(SELECT COUNT(PT) FROM staff WHERE PT = 'T' ) FROM staff GROUP BY ward)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

but then I get this table

```
staff
ward | P | T
1    | 3 | 2
2    | 2 | 2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case statements will work here:

```
SELECT
    ward,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pt = P THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pt = T THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    ward
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select ward, sum( (pt = 'P')::int ) as p, sum ( (pt = 'T')::int ) as t
from t
group by ward;
```